# Reading UTF-8 file using wbuffer_convert in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8

I'm trying to read UTF-8 file and convert characters to wchar_t using std::wbuffer_convert:

```
std::ifstream fl( "./file.txt" );
std::wbuffer_convert< std::codecvt_utf8< wchar_t > > conv( fl.rdbuf() );
std::wistream istr( &conv );
std::istreambuf_iterator< wchar_t > it( istr.rdbuf() ), end;
while ( it != end )
{
    // Some work
    ++it;
}
```

But somewhy this method reads fails to read the entire file.
It stops and some moment at it == end, while it's far from the end of the file.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the file is valid UTF-8 and representable in `wchar_t`?

Comment: Yes. I tried several files, converted with iconv.

Comment: Can you upload a sample file? Also: platform, compiler, standard library?

Comment: Are you sure your iterator usage is correct? Maybe try using `for(wchar_t c; istr.get(c);)` instead.

Comment: ecatmur, sample is here: http://royallib.com/get/txt/tolkin_dgon/vlastelin_kolets.zip

Comment: Remy, I believe, the problem is about iterator usage. The question is: how to do it correctly?